# Firefox information disclosure caused by screenshots of recently used websites

Tags: html, security, google-chrome, firefox, screenshot

With my web application I've noticed that on the "New Tab" page it shows a series of my recently view websites with screenshots.

The problem here is that some of these screen shots show sensitive information from my web page.

Is there a way to block Firefox from taking screen shots of my web application in particular without requiring browser configurations (in my website code)?

I believe chrome has a similar feature, I would like to block it as well.

Comment: +1 for the question, but I guess it is offtopic here and belongs on superuser instead

Comment: @Jacco I disagree: The OP is looking for a solution involving the website's source code, not the browser.

Comment: ah, I see I misread the question.

Comment: I agree with @Jacco - except I think it should be **webmasters.stackexchange.com**

Comment: @RivieraKid This question is not specific to web masters; It is also applicable to offline web apps. The question is clear, the answer would probably contain code. This question is perfectly on-topic on Stack Overflow (there are 4 close-as-off-topic votes already..).

Comment: Cleared Off topic votes; although this question doesn't specify a language, so you're going to need to specify which language you want the solution in.  Also, there's a strong chance that this won't be solvable.

Comment: I'm going to tag it HTML because that's the most likely candidate - *if* there is a solution, which indeed looks doubtful

Comment: I doubt you can prevent this, unless you have a way to prevent the user from taking screen shots manually, or of taking photos using his cell phone camera.

Comment: I think we need to add *Javascript, applets and anything else* that lets the webpage interact with the web-browser as a tag.. My answer of course concludes that this is not possible either way and should not be possible in the future too..

Comment: Good question, I think this identifies a missing feature for the current crop of browsers - it should be possible to specify the large image used on new tab pages or when a screenshot can be taken/refreshed in a similar way to the favicon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could set the cache-control header. This would tell the browser to make all possible efforts not to save the page on the user's computer.

```
Cache-control: no-store
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Avoiding_caching

Sadly, this would be a performance hit since the user would need to pull down each page entirely for every call they make.

Answer (score 1):

**[UPDATED]**

Short answer: **No.**

Long answer:

This clearly goes beyond the scope of **HTML** that deals with presentation of the content *within the browser's chrome*.
Here's an example why it there isn't such an option supported by browsers as yet.

> Consider browsers that remember what was types in text-fields and
>   thereby provide auto-complete functionality when the user starts
>   typing into a text-field having the same/similar class names/IDs.
>
> Now Gecko browsers came up with the
>   [autocomplete="off"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)
>   attribute to let the web-designer control the **presentation** of the
>   form. So while browsers may come up with ways for you to manage the presentation of the data on the web-browser there isn't a way to manage the presentation of the page beyond the browser's chrome (portion of browser used to display the page).

For clarification, one can refer to the formal definition of HTML [here](http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss).

Now that HTML has been ruled out, lets look at [ECMA script](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf). The ECMA script determines what Javascript can and cannot do.. there are different implementation of this but ultimately the functionality remains more or less the same in order for the implementations to be *ECMA compliant*. Looking at the ECMA functionality it confirms that Javascript will not do more than access cookies and issue functions to indirectly control the browsers history.

These [screenhsots](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thumbnails-on-new-tab-page-are-missing) are taken by the browser and cached on the local disk. They are cached and accessible using a link as follows: `moz-page-thumb://thumbnail?url=<url encoded>`, eg. `moz-page-thumb://thumbnail?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F`

> Disclaimer: The following conclusion is based on my understanding for which I cannot provide any references. HTML or Javascript will definitely not help you here; browser specific add-ons would be the solution. Webdesigners should not be able to control the usage of the web-content once it reaches my machine, as that would infer invasion of privacy.

Comment: Do you have any references to support your claims (being an authoritative figure in the right field is also OK)? Otherwise, your post is not quite valuable, unfortunately. Answers are expected to be based on facts, not opinions or speculation.

Comment: @RobW I have provided references for my claims.. Had a look at the FAQ again.. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my own Firefox's 'New Tab' window, it seems that FF doesn't take screenshots of web pages accessed via https. Those pages appear with a blank rectangle. This totally makes sense to me and I hope it's not just a weird coincidence for me.

If that's the case, in my opinion any part of a website that handles sensitive information should be secured and FF won't capture an image of it.

Comment: This answer is incorrect: Github and some pages from my university are served over SSL, and I still see thumbnails (Firefox). In Chrome, the Chrome web store is served over SSL and again, a thumbnail is displayed.

Comment: After some testing I too have found that SSL pages are shown as well.

Comment: Well... I'm really sorry for the mislead, guys. It's just that it really is true in my case. Every website that I have to log into via https doesn't have a thumbnail: facebook, gmail, yahoo. Maybe it's that those websites have the solution? Or maybe it's just my FF failing to take the snapshot in some cases...

Answer (score 0):

Read this [New Tab Page – show, hide and customize top sites](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/new-tab-page-show-hide-and-customize-top-sites)

Comment: op needs a solution from the website's standpoint, not from the user's.

Comment: i think my answer somehow addresses that, since securing the website via https seems to solve the problem. not 100% sure, more user testimonies would help. e.g. is there someone that has firefox capturing images of https pages?

Comment: @AlexMihai not all sites can be accessed through https... But maybe its the best that he can do

Comment: @Loclip It's better to summarize the link in your post and then link to it. Otherwise, if the link moves, your answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends where on your website the sensitive information is shown.

Solution 1: HTTPS. Browsers understand that https sites need more security, so won't include https sites in the speed dial page. (frankly, if it's sensitive information, you should be using https anyway, since http pages can be read by attackers via a number of means beyond looking at the screenshots).

Solution 2: Only show the sensitive information "below the fold". The screenshots are the top part of the page, so if the information in question is lower on the page, it won't show up in the screenshots.

Solution 3: Give the page with the sensitive information a unique URL every time it's opened. Browsers only show the most-opened URLs in the quick-dial screen, so if its a different URL every time, it'll never show up.